# Hot to check if new posts have been published since page load and notify online users?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, query-posts

I want to show a div notifying online users that there are new posts since they have accessed the page, in the index and also if new posts have been added in the category or tag they are browsing.

I have been trying for hours to find a script that does exactly what I need, but I have not found anything exact, and my programming level is very low. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You can use cookies to store the last post id and compare current last post's id when the revisit.

Comment: If there's nothing in the [wp.org plugins repo](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/) it will be a very difficult task to talk you through this online - I would suggest posting a job for a developer. The simplest way is to run an Ajax poll periodically on your site when a user is visiting - this can check for new posts for a category / post type depending on which type of post or category you're viewing.